# Where can i find the files of exe installation?

Tags: wine, executable

Where can i find the files of exe installation as i'm using wine to install exe file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a hidden directory ".wine" in your home directory.
So do

```
cd ~/.wine/
```

and in there is a Windows oriented directory structure.

Of if you want to do this from the file explorer: go to your home dir and do CONTROL H and it will show hidden files then navigate into the .wine directory.

Mind that you should be using the internal browser inside wine if you want to do anything with the EXE. Altering it from Ubuntu can/will corrupt the file.

Comment: does crack file work in Ubuntu as windows ?

Comment: No, it does not Are you asking to help you with illegal activities? If so please read this site rules.

Comment: yes i know what are the illegal activities ! but need to know this information .. is this forbidden ? thanks at all for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

you can show your code with

1. show location your terminal now

```
pwd
```

show your location folder with all folder hidden file

```
ls --all
```

if you have found the destination folder, you just run with the command

```
cd ~/.wine/
```